# is-port-reachable getting results in a loop using promises

Tags: node.js, generator

Im using `is-port-reachable` package that returns promise. I would like to find first free (not reachable) port. So I should perform `IsPortReachable` in loop. Im trying to use `yield`, but have an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word` (yield couldBeBinded). If I move yield outside promise an error will disappear.

```
findPort () {
    function * checkPort() {
      let couldBeBinded = false;

      let port = this.port;

      do {
        IsPortReachable(this.port, {host: 'localhost'})
          .then(function (reachable) {
            "use strict";

            if (!reachable) { // not binded
              couldBeBinded = true;
            } else {
              port++;
            }

            if (port > 65534) {
              return couldBeBinded;
            }

            yield couldBeBinded;
          });
      } while(!couldBeBinded && (port < 65534));
    }

    var generator = checkPort();
    let couldBeBinded = { value: false, done: false };
    while((couldBeBinded.value !== true) && (couldBeBinded.done !== false)) {
      couldBeBinded = generator.next();
      console.log(couldBeBinded);
    }
}
```

May be my code is totally wrong, so please advice me how to loop promises on `node`. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution to this problem:

```
const IsPortReachable = require('is-port-reachable');

var options = {
  start_port : 2994,
  end_port : 3003,
  findFirstFree : true
}

function CheckPort(port, firstFree, callback) {
  IsPortReachable(port, {host: 'localhost'})
    .then((reachable) => {
      if (reachable) {
        console.log(port, "reachable");
        if (firstFree) callback(port);
      }
      else {
        console.log(port, "free")
        if (!firstFree) callback(port);
      }
    })
}

function CheckPortHandler(port, firstFree) {
    if (port >= options.end_port) return;
    CheckPort(port + 1, firstFree, CheckPortHandler)
}

CheckPort(options.start_port, options.findFirstFree, CheckPortHandler);
```

You can change the start and end port in the options. If you want to find the first reachable port (as opposed to first free port) change `findFirstFree` to `false`.

In the code I'm creating a function `CheckPort` that wraps around `IsPortReachable` but also receives a callback. The callback is called if the `reachable` status does not agree with the `firstFree` parameter. The callback is another function that calls `CheckPort` again with an incremented port, so the process continues. It continues until the `reachable` status agrees with the `firstFree` param, so the callback is no longer called.

It might be a bit confusing but it works ok for me.

Here is the output with `findFirstFree : true`

```
2994 'free'
```

And the output with `findFirstFree : false`

```
2994 'free'
2995 'free'
2996 'free'
2997 'free'
2998 'free'
2999 'free'
3000 'reachable'
```